# D8016 '/clr' and '/MT' command-line options are incompatible

Tags: c++, c, windows, winforms, clr

I have made an Windows Application using visual c++[CLR Empty Project].But when I run that .exe file in another PC i get error of **ucrtbased.dll, VCRUNTIME140D and MSVCP140D file is missing.**

For this, we have changed the Runtime Library from Multi-threaded Debug DLL(/MDd) to Multi-threaded(/MT). Then also i am getting error like :-

Error : **D8016 '/clr' and '/MT' command-line options are incompatible.**

So, if any one have any idea to resolve this problem will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: The DLLs with names following the pattern: `*D.dll` are debugging versions of the Runtime Support DLLs.  You must not distribute these.  Instead build a Release version of your project and if there are still missing Runtime Support DLLs use the the Redistributable installer to install them. [Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable latest supported downloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170)

Comment: Change it from `/MDd` to `/MD`. You don't need to go all the way to `/MT`. That will stop requirement on debug versions of the DLLs. You'll then need release version, but most people have those but if not see @RichardCritten comment. (Also note that if you used the normal create-project wizard then you'll already have a DEBUG and a RELEASE build type, and using the RELEASE build type will have /MD already set and then you're good to go.